# Set Variable inside (document).ready for all functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Really new to jQuery and this had been baffling me for a while.

**I'll use this as an example:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#link1 a").hover(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.css("color", "#fff");
        });
    });
```

Obviously enough, this will change the color of the a inside #link1 to white on hover.

**THIS is what I was trying to do:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

      var $this = $(this);

      $("#link1 a").hover(function(){
        $this.css("color", "#fff");
      });

      $("#link2 a").hover(function(){
        $this.css("color", "#f00");
      });
    });
```

This doesn't work.

Am I able to set var $this = $(this); inside (document).ready so it works with all functions inside it?

Sorry if this is a silly question, couldn't find an answer anywhere else.  Wasn't 100% sure to search for if I'm honest!

Comment: It's all about scope. Don't define `this` outside of the hover event. You want it inside the event handler so it refers to the element being hovered.

Comment: it's a silly question, because `this` in that scope is the document and can't be styled with a style property.

Comment: As already mentioned, that doesn't really make sense, since inside each event handler, `this` something different. The value of `$this` doesn't *magically* change depending on where it is accessed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your statement `var $this = $(this);` while valid, doesn't achieve what you need. If you think about it... THIS is referring to `$(document)`

So, if you change your code to this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#link1 a").hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css("color", "#fff");
  }); //In this case $this refers to $("#link1 a")

  $("#link2 a").hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css("color", "#f00");
  }); //In this case $this refers to $("#link2 a")
});
```

however, that is not really necessary, as you can just do this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#link1 a").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("color", "#fff");
  });

  $("#link2 a").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("color", "#f00");
  });
});
```

Now if you wanted to increase the scope of `$this` you can do something like so :

```
$(a).hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    //now if you wanted to check for which link is currently hovered you can say this :
    var link = $this.attr("id");
    //this will set link equal to the current id

    //NOW you can have if statements checking which link it is...
    if(link == "link1") { ... do stuff }
    if(link == "link2") { ... do other stuff }
}
```

also, if you are using JQuery version POST 1.7 you should be calling events like so :

```
$(a).on("hover", function () {
    ...some function
});
```

Lastly, don't be afraid to look at the JQuery API for some help with things... it is very well written and provides examples

### https://api.jquery.com/

Comment: So I guess the reason I asked was because I didn't want to define $this for one thing.  I wanted to define it inside a broader area so I can use it more than once?  Seems like that's bad practice though I guess?

Comment: @Nick well, what would be the purpose of defining it outside? wouldn't you need it to target the element being hovered rather than all links affecting the same element?

Comment: `$(this)` can be set to a group of elements, you just have to do it right. if you wanted to use it for every link item you could say something like `$(a).each(function() { var $this = $(this)... });` and then in every case `$this` will refer to the current `<a>` element

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could select everything -

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $this = $('*'); // all elements in the DOM for this page

});
```

I don't recommend it though, why are you doing this?

Comment: Makes sense to me. This doesn't answer the question at all, and doesn't explain why the OP's code isn't working as he expected.

Comment: His question - Set Variable inside (document).ready for all functions? is answered by selecting all, even if I don't recommend it.

Comment: Are you answering the title or answering the question?

Comment: His title is a question :) Furthermore in his post he asks, "Am I able to set var $this = $(this); inside (document).ready so it works with all functions inside it?" To which I replied "No, but..."